# Sensor multi-threading Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I'm building a strength testing machine using a Raspberry Pi, a load cell (through an HX711 chip) and a  4-20mA Laser distance sensor (read through an MCP3008 ADC). The Pi has a while loop which uses these inputs through a Pololu motor controller to drive a brushless DC linear actuator (using a PWM with a PID controller).

I've profiled the code, and it seems that most of the time is being spent reading the HX711 and the ADC, so I'd like to get these two tasks running in parallel so that I can get better time resolution on the sensor (at the moment it's only managing to take about 3 samples/s).

I've created two classes (one to read the load cell, the other to read the ADC). I want to get maximum speed-up whilst ensuring I don't allow the sensors to get out of sync with each other. Which functionality of the threading class should I use to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: RPi does not have any "loops". Its is the library you use. Just write another not blocking one

Comment: You could have a controller thread that sends each reader a "start" message on a separate message queue and waits for a reply from both with the reading before sending the next "start" message. The readers would each then sit in a tight loop, blocking, waiting for a "start" message, then reading and sending back the reading on the same queue.